# How to open a webpage from an arduino uno

Tags: ide, arduino, html, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

I was wondering if it's possible to open an internet browser from code in your arduino IDE or any other sort of program connected to the arduino and in turn open a specific webpage.

My idea was to have a button on my arduino uno, once pressed, it would open a browser and a webpage in that browser on my connected computer.

I don't mind if the answer involves code outside of the arduino but it would be great if someone has an idea about how to do this sort of thing.

I've done a lot of research and I couldn't find anything relating to the topic which surprises me a lot as this seems like a simple task, anyway any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't found anything related to it, because nobody wants to make an Arduino do what you can easily do with a couple clicks.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to open a web page with the help of arduino.
But all of them have on thing in common and that is:
1.You receive the data in your PC
2.You tell your PC if the desired data is received open a webpage.

The best way I can think of telling you pc to open a web page is through a programming language. This could be C#,Java,Processing or any other language that has a library that support to monitor the serial port.
After that all you have to do is to say with the help of programming language if this received then open web page..
Here ara two useful links that might be of help:

[http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=138974.0](http://whichlight.com/blog/arduino-serial-out-to-browser/comment-page-1/)

http://whichlight.com/blog/arduino-serial-out-to-browser/comment-page-1/

Comment: While it deals with using an AVR chip itself, rather than an Arduino board, Make just had a good article on doing exactly this, and the PC side of the code (in Python) would be the same, and the C code very similar. See http://makezine.com/projects/make-41-tinkering-toys/avr-usart-serial/

Answer (score 1):

The cheap and easy way would be to [make your Arduino appear as a USB keyboard](http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/) and simulate the keypresses required. Of course, this is prone to breakage if the user is typing, not very cross-platform, etc. but it is fairly simple and doesn't require a program on the machine. I received a small USB dongle attached to an ad once that did this. They found a key combination that worked on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

With an ASP.Net application you can easily do that,here is a a tutorial on [this](https://hashben.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/send-data-from-arduino-to-asp-net-c-web-application/) issue.
And after getting a signal from arduino all you have to do is to write in ASP.NET to open the required link

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its totally possible given that you know how to code in python.

You can have your own program running that will monitor request from arduino uno using serial port. When it receives a particular set of bytes (say "0xabcdef"), it will call the function to open a browser and a web page.

Here are some of the sites that will help you know how to interface arduino to python and opening web browser using python.

http://www.olgapanades.com/blog/controlling-arduino-with-python/

https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html